# Custom CSS inside another CSS element

Tags: html, css

I'm using a Wordpress Theme and now need to customize one of its elements styles. (*that element is automatically showing our tours*)
Right now, the style is:

```
.tourmaster-tour-grid .tourmaster-tour-content-wrap {
    min-height: 250px;
}
```

I assigned a custom CSS class to the element: **hp_tour_el**. And I changed it to:

```
.hp_tour_el .tourmaster-tour-grid .tourmaster-tour-content-wrap {
    min-height: 160px;
    height: 130px;
}
```

But it didn't change anything.

Comment: `.hp-tour-dv` or `hp_tour_el` ??

Comment: try to use `min-height: 160px!important;` to your new style (with the correct class name)

Comment: @לבנימלכה why not `height: 160px`...?

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @לבנימלכה I made a mistake when I write the code here in stackoverflow, now I edited the code

Comment: Try this `.hp_tour_el { max-height: 160px !important; height: 130px !important;}`

Comment: @Awais Thanks Awais. But it didn't work either. I think because that element showing our tours automatically, I can't assign any style to it. When I put .hp_tour_el into my inspect, it turned into inactive mode.

Comment: @Awais [link](https://imgur.com/UzyZ0MD)

Comment: @Sadegh Its becuase their is some other selector with #id which makes it unimportant and also use `!important`. Please show us the live link of your site

Comment: @Awais I see, I think that is the reason then. Here is a link to our website, you can find the division under the main banner of website, when 4 tours are showing up: [link](https://nomad.tours/)

Comment: @Sadegh You are not targeting the selector correctly, as i can see their is no above mention class `hp_tour_el` so its not targeting. Just add the calss on section then let me know i ll make your selector for CSS

Comment: @Awais You're right, I'm not targeting the selector. But I've just added the class on the section, and it still doesn't target it. You can check it now

Comment: Added the ans below @Sadegh please have a look and do let me know of its working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I finally figured it out th issue is you are not setting `min-height`
>   which is `250px` while you are setting height to `170px` which is less
>   then min so set `min-height` to `auto` and then use `height`to your
>   desire value

```
.hp_tour_el .tourmaster-tour-content-wrap {
    height: 140px;
    min-height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are right. I had to set the min-height to auto as you said. Thanks again for your kind help